# How to ensure that you only get a single claim returned on a SPARQL query in Wikidata?

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

This is a wikidata to get the TED talks ID for an individual. Even though the TED ID field is constrained to a single value, two have been entered, this means that this query returns two rows. I would just like to get one of the two claims (the default one??? I don't really care which) returned.

https://w.wiki/5RVk

```
SELECT ?itemLabel ?TED

WHERE {
  VALUES ?item {
    wd:Q321698
  }
  {
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P2611 ?TED. }
  }
}
GROUP BY ?itemLabel ?TED
```

I don't really want to group them - but I could fall back on that.

Comment: you have to group them and then take a `sample` of it of you just want one of many

Comment: `SELECT ?itemLabel (sample(?TED_) as ?TED)

WHERE {
  VALUES ?item {
    wd:Q321698
  }
  {
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P2611 ?TED_ . }
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?itemLabel`